# word automation fails when run as scheduled task

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, scheduler

I have a console application which generates a word file. Normally the application runs fine but it failing when run through a scheduled task.

All i get is the following error message

> ERROR    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.SaveAs2(Object& FileName,
>   Object& FileFormat, Object& LockComments, Object& Password, Object&
>   AddToRecentFiles, Object& WritePassword, Object& ReadOnlyRecommended,
>   Object& EmbedTrueTypeFonts, Object& SaveNativePictureFormat, Object&
>   SaveFormsData, Object& SaveAsAOCELetter, Object& Encoding, Object&
>   InsertLineBreaks, Object& AllowSubstitutions, Object& LineEnding,
>   Object& AddBiDiMarks, Object& CompatibilityMode)    at
>   YearBook.DirectoryGenerator.DirectoryGenerator.GenerateDirectory(String&
>   filePath)

I am running the scheduled under the administrator account and also tried using the option **Run with highest privileges**

I had to use the word automation as I need a very complex indexing feature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like a stacktrace. What is the type of Exception object? And what is the exception message? Does it happen all the time, or just from time to time?

Comment: First thing to look at and ignoring the problem of running a UI program from a scheduled task is what Path are you trying to save the file to?  Is it the same path when you run from a console and related to your user account?

Comment: Yes that is the stack trace and it happens every time when i run through the scheduler. I cannot debug it to see the type of exception object?

Comment: @MikeBurdick I am saving the file in a folder on same path where the exe is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it failing when run through a scheduled task.

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Comment: Any better ways to generate a pdf with index and table of contents ?

Comment: You can use any third-party components designed for the server-side execution and that don't required Word to be installed on the system. One of the possible solutions is to use the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for generating documents.